# Difference between the UpdateOne() and findOneAndUpdate Methods in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, insert-update, mongodb-update

What is the difference between the `UpdateOne()` and the `findOneAndUpdate()` methods in Mongo DB?
I can't seem o understand their differences. Would appreciate it if a demonstrative example using `UpdateOne()` and `findOneAndUpdate` could be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert a document in an otherwise empty collection using the `mongo-shell` to start:

```
db.users.insertOne({name: "Jack", age: 11})
```

#### UpdateOne

```
db.users.updateOne({name: "Jack"}, {$set: {name: "Joe"}})
```

This operation returns an `UpdateResult`.

```
{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedCount: 0 }
```

#### FindOneAndUpdate

```
db.users.findOneAndUpdate({name: "Joe"}, {$set: {name: "Jill"}})
```

This operation returns the document that was updated.

```
{ _id: ObjectId("62ecf94510fc668e92f3cecf"),
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 11 }
```

`FindOneAndUpdate` is preferred when you have to update a document and fetch it at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return the **New Document** instead of the original document, you can use one of these ways:

```MongoDB
db.users.findOneAndUpdate(
  {name: "Joe"},
  {$set: {name: "Jill"}},
  {returnDocument: "after"}
)
```

*returnDocument: "before"* --> returns the original document (default).
*returnDocument: "after"* --> returns the updated document.

Or

```MongoDB
db.users.findOneAndUpdate(
  {name: "Joe"},
  {$set: {name: "Jill"}},
  {returnNewDocument: true}
)
```

*returnNewDocument: false* --> returns the original document (default).
*returnNewDocument: true* --> returns the updated document.

Note: If both options are set (*returnDocument* and *returnNewDocument*), *returnDocument* takes precedence.